# hide webparts from webpart Gallery

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to crate a feature which hides some specific webparts within webpart gallery and even the Categories of that webparts to prevent users to add webparts to the pages.
is it possible? 
thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can set permissions at web part level in the web part gallery. If you want finer control over what's available and even dynamically adding web part to the gallery, please visit an excellent article written by Victor: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Dynamically-populate-the-Web-Part-Gallery-using-the-WebPartAdder-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

and also: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/controlling-available-web-parts-web-part-adder/